# Swift: Defining new three Dimensional Array with different types inside of array

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I am trying to define a new multi dimensional array to .append() with a tuple later. I have the following code, but get a syntax error.

```
var roundTricks: [[(String,Int)],[(String,Int)]] = [[],[]]
```

The goal is to update the array of tuples using the following code:

```
var editID = 0

var name = "Hello World"
var points = 5
roundTricks[editID].append((name, points))
```

The error I get when I try to define the array is: `Expected ']' in array type`, `Expected Pattern`

I'm sure its an easy solution, just can't find an answer that deals with tuples and multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Lookin at your comment, I now realize that the type is throwing an error because it is completely custom. I did mean what I typed, but I also realize that the type I defined is not possible to define.

Comment: It looks like you might want something closer to `[Int:[(String:Int)]]`. That's a `Dictionary` with a key of type `Int` and values that are an `Array` of the tuple `(String,Int)`. Note that many times you're better off defining a struct than using a tuple. It takes a few minutes and is far more clear and extensible.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a typealias for your tuple type, then either use an array (as you have), or a dictionary (as per @ColGraff's suggestion).

```
typealias Trick = (String, Int)

var roundTricksArray: [[Trick]] = [[], []]
var roundTricksDict: [Int: [Trick]] = [:]

var editID = 0
var name = "Hello World"
var points = 5

roundTricksArray[editID].append((name, points))
roundTricksDict[editID] = [(name, points)]
```